# Grails - Read, customize and attach a word document

Tags: grails, ms-word, doc

I need to do the following (with Grails):

> 1. Read a word template
> 2. Add user details (e.g. name, last name) to the document
> 3. Send the customized word by mail

I am thinking in Apache POI to read .doc, then in the document I will have keywords e.g."°!"#$" and make the customization. 
Then I will create the document, send it (with Grails plugin) and erase the document from the server

Is this a good approach or I am forgetting something?
Thank you very much

EDIT:
DOCx4j: My docx operations are simple, so I can go with the "approach 1" in the variable replace, 
but for some reason the next sample is not working for me: 
https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java

I'm getting a:

```
| Error 2014-03-27 09:10:23,640 [http-bio-9000-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SAXParseException occurred when processing request: [POST] /Estrategia/pasantiaCorta/generarDocumento
Content is not allowed in prolog.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

In the line:

// Approach 1 (from 3.0.0; faster if you haven't yet caused unmarshalling to occur):

```
documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach at all. It's very similar to something we already do but we use JasperReports to generate the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use POI or docx4j.  For either, you'd be much better off using docx rather than the legacy binary doc format.

For docx4j (my project), see [creating-word-docx-documents-dynamically-from-grails](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/11/04/creating-word-docx-documents-dynamically-from-grails--or-java----.html)

At your step 2 (add user details), there are a [variety of approaches](http://www.slideshare.net/plutext) you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason; I choosed docx4j to try it;
Please read the new edit!

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog" is the XML parser complaining you have junk characters at the start of some XML document - possibly a "part" of your docx.  Not a known error for docx4j and proper docx files. Do you have the stack trace?  If you can put a docx causing that error online somewhere, I'll check how docx4j (without grails) treats it.  Or you can do that yourself by uploading it to the docx4j webapp.

Comment: Ooops, this is embarassing. I was searching for different solutions but you were right again; the problem was the docx I was tryining to use! (It had "revisions" so if you are using VariableReplace, you need to first call to VariablePrepare in that case) Thank you very much, everything is working now :)